# Should I calculate poststratification weights on the entire dataset, or just the test set?

Tags: classification, survey, survey-weights

I'm currently working on a classification task where certain features were intentionally oversampled, so I calculated  using the R `survey` package to adjust my model evaluation based on the true population proportions.  I am not using the weights as a feature when training models; rather I am using them to adjust the ROC curves using the R `PRROC`.

Should I be calculating these poststratification weights on the entire dataset, or just the test set?